# Windows Account Password Resetting process for large network

Tags: passwords, windows, rest

I am working on large windows based network environment (Active Directory) and I have a requirement of implementing clear and secure password reset process for windows user. Especially management requested to use same process for all applications which are using in our factory.

Currently we ask them to raise help desk ticket and IT team will reset according to their request. But we have security issue on this process because if windows password is lost, he ask to raise ticket to another user. Therefore any user can request password change for someone else.

what would be technical solution and process to avoid this security issue and reset user password securely.

Answer (score 1):

> Currently we ask them to raise help desk ticket and the IT team will reset according to their request. But we have a security issue on this process because if widows password is lost he ask to raise a ticket to another user. Therefore any user can request a password change for someone else.

Indeed, in some companies, it's possible to request a password reset even by phone.

> what would be a technical solution and process to avoid this security issue and reset user password securely.

In theory, the service-desk should validate the requesting user - e.g. check the calling phone number or call back the user to a registered (company) phone

In our company, we have a self-service service (web page), where users could register their alternate phone numbers, emails (e.g. private emails), security questions. In that case, they could reset their domain password themselves.

Comment: can you give me little more information about self-service portal in your company? how do you access it? and how it is functioning?

Comment: @Infra I am not sure what are you asking for. The user needs to enroll its alternate email or security questions upfront (while having access). The service is available publicly (having many off-site people). Still - there is a risk that someone using a simple security questions can be impersonated. Btw - almost all IAM solutions could provide such a service (WSO2 IS, OpenAM, Okta ..)

Answer (score 1):

I work in a IT-department at a University, where students and employees forget their passwords all the time. Each user has a unique username and an email within the domain. Below is the bare minimum process and you can add several factors like **date of birth** etc. to make it more secure.

**Please note that there are several systems integrated with Active Directory that can handle this automatically, but this is the process explained.**

- Before the user is registered in the domain, you should collect the
  information about them like **first-** and **surname**, **phone number** and
  their **email address** in a database. Already you've set identifiers for this individual.
- Whenever the individual sends the helpdesk an email (with the address
  you got registered) regarding a password reset, you can easily verify
  this up to their username through Active Directory and in your database.
- When the user has been verified, you should send a text to their phone with the new password. Sending passwords over email is **NOT** secure, unless it's encrypted.

As an additional note, you should also let the users know what the mail requires for a password reset to make the verification process easier and shorter for the IT-team.

Comment: The problem in question is when the users are unable to access their email address. It's easier if the user could drop by the helpdesk and they could physically check the user's identity. In big companies (manly with off-site people) it may be tricky

Comment: @gusto2 And I describe how to solve it in my answer. Storing their private email address in a database. If they've lost access to their private email address - that is not part of the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

A secure password reset is always a security nightmare. To solve it, you have to find a way to securely identify the requester without asking them their password. It is easy if the application password is not the email password because you then have an *alternate channel* to send a *secret* that allows to enter a reset password application.

If users are never alone, they could ask a deskmate to send the request from their account, the help_desk (or the automatic system) logs to request sender and sends them a *one time secret token* by mail. They can then give that token to the original user and it works. The key here is that anybody can ask for a password reset token for any other user, but the request is logged. So if the system is abused, team managers will act *in the real world*.

If users can work from home, then you have to set up the alternate channel through their personnal e-mail, but you should first contact the legal service because storing in a database the personnal e-mail of employees can have legal implications in some countries - from no problem at all to strictly forbidden passing by *you need declare it to employee representatives and have a signed agreement from every employee entitled to use that system*.

Long story made short, it will boil down to *how can I securely identify somebody without exchanging a pre-shared secret (the lost password)*. Above ways are *another human being*, or *an alternate e-mail address*. You will have to find the less bad solution for you real use case (which may be a third way...).